# whether or not this code is integer overflow

Tags: c

I saw this code somewhere, is this not integer overflow and undefined behaviour?

assume `0 < str[i] < 127`

```
char *msl_decrypt(char *str) {
    char *decrypted;
    unsigned int i;
    int key = 0xFACA;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) {
        str[i] = str[i] + key; // referring to this line, is it UB?
    }
    ...
```

Comment: And the answer is: maybe!

Comment: @Olaf No unsigned integers are part of the calculation in question.

Comment: If anything it's a byte overflow since `str[i]` is of type `char`

Comment: and the question was downvoted because?

Comment: @DanielJour: You are wrong. `char` has no standard signed-ness.

Comment: @RPGillespie: Wrong! The calculation is done as `int`. There is only a conversion to `char` for the assignment.

Comment: @Olaf I wasn't really sure, but that's why I said "if anything" because it's clearly impossible to overflow an integer (of any kind) by adding a 16-bit and 8-bit number together.

Comment: @RPGillespie: Why do you think they are 8 and 16 bits? This is not given in the question. And if `int` is 16 bits, the problem are the initialiser (still not UB) and the addition (potentially UB). Problems multiply if `CHAR_BIT >= 16`.

Comment: Regarding the edit: As given, the array is not properly terminated! (`0 < str[i]`! You might want to add two `=` (one for the upper bound).

Comment: I'd say it hardly matters whether it's undefined, because (a) it's silly to be adding a 16-bit key to 8-bit bytes in this way, and much more importantly, (b) the "security" of the encryption involved here is nonexistent.  Don't worry whether it's undefined, implementation-defined, or well-defined -- pick a better algorithm, pronto!

Comment: @RPGillespie a 16-bit int can be overflowed by adding an 8-bit value (or even a 1-bit value). Otherwise you could add 1 forever...

Comment: @M.M I was assuming that OP was using 32-bit or 64-bit integers, since you only encounter 16-bit integers in very rare circumstances (i.e. microcontrollers)

Comment: or MS-DOS systems. Apparently a lot of people still use Turbo C

Comment: @SteveSummit: Agreed about this cannot be called "encryption". But similar algorithms are well used, e.g. to calculate a checksum. See TCP for an example.

Comment: @RPGillespie: There are some decades more microcontrollers than Server- + PC + larger ARM -CPUs. Actually every PC has some MCUs: HDD, Mainboard, Keyboard, Mouse, DVD/CD/BD, etc. Even the CPU might have an integrated MCU for e.g. power management.

Comment: "since you only encounter 16-bit integers in very rare circumstances (i.e. microcontrollers) " --> not even close - 100s of millions of 16 bit processors were made each year about 2014.

Answer (score 5):

Too bad you did not specify the target parameters. So for the following I presume:

- `CHAR_BIT == 8`
- `sizeof(int) >= 2`
- not padding bits
- `str` points to valid and initialised memory which is properly `nul`-terminated and not larger than `INT_MAX` (alternatively use `size_t` to index - thanks @chux).
- and possibly other prerequisites we tend to take for given.

These are typical for most modern implementations.

For `sizeof(int) == 2`, the initialiser is implementation defined behaviour, because you use an `unsigned int` constant as initialiser. For wider `int` this is ok. Things also become more complicated if `(int)(0xFACA) + CHAR_MAX > INT_MAX` (arithmetically, also only relevant for 2 byte `int`).

The rest relies on *implementation defined behaviour* in a more complex way:

1) The addition `str[i] + key`: Here `str[i]` is converted to `int` first, the addition is done as `int` and yields an `int` result.

2) The assignment `str[i] = ...`: Here the `int` result of the addition is converted to `char`. For that we have two variants, depending on the signed-ness of `char` (implementation defined):

- unsigned: The result is converted in a standard defined way to `unsigned char`.
- signed: The result is "down-"convert to the "smaller" `signed char` in an implementation defined way.

So: **no** *undefined behaviour*, but that (and the comments) shows how much you have to keep in mind when using signed integers in C.

---

**But:**

There is too much *implementation defined behaviour* involved and a lot of prerequisites are required (which are quite common, though). Better use `unsigned char` and `unsigned int` throughout the code. That will make the code standard compliant and well-behaved. Even for other than `CHAR_BIT` values. If you rely on 8 bit values, use `uint8_t` from `stdint.h`.

Comment: Another required assumption would be that `int key = 0xFACA;` generates an `int` which is not within 127 of `INT_MAX`

Comment: @M.M: Yes; I also added that (just in some more general form). But please don't ask to remove the prerequisites and make all text general; It's getting later here;-).

Comment: if you can slightly more elaborate why you assumed those prerequisites would be nice

Comment: @user200312: Because things get even more messed up if e.g. `SCHAR_MAX == INT_MAX`. The `ptr` related prerequiste should be clear.

Comment: why the padding bits requirement?

Comment: @user200312: Please be more specific. I already wrote that without the constraints things become far more complicated. I hardly can cite the complete standard. In case you are on an x86, ARM, AVR, Coldfire, PPC, POWER, SPARC, MIPS, and many more, you are on the safe side anyway.